# TypeError summing a list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'd like to find the sum of the elements in a list using a loop. I must be able to apply this generically if inputting different lists.

I have tried the simple

```
print(sum(numbers))
```

and it returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.

When I tried adding each individually, I found out that the list changes. The original list is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`. When I added each element using

```
int(numbers[0]) + int(number[1]) # ...
```

when I get to index 4, there isn't a value for the index.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I can't reproduce this--please show your actual list and full code to reproduce the problem as a [mcve]. Are you taking these numbers as input by chance? I'm guessing you may have forgotten to cast a string input to integer with `int(input("enter a number"))` or `list(map(int, input("Enter a list of numbers separated by whitespace: ").split()))`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure by what you mean, because you haven't included much code, but I believe I can answer part of it.

It's hard to know why you're having indexing errors without seeing the code you wrote, but I imagine Because you may have been removing them as you added them up.

Maybe try using an accumulator variable, which would result in python code that might look like

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4]
total = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)): #loops through for exactly the number of items in the list
    sum = total + numbers[i]
```

This won't change any of the items in the list, leaving intact, and leaving you with the variable `sum` that is equal to the total sum of the list.